# Errores en metodo para producto vectorial

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un programa que me permita realizar producto vectorial entre dos vectores utilizando métodos obligatoriamente, me aparecen tres errores. Dos de tipo:

> ']' expected

y uno de

> identifier expected

todos en la fila donde inicia el metodo para el producto ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Mi código es :

```
static int productocruz(int veccruz[], int vector1[i] , int vector2[i]){
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        veccruz[i] = 0;
        veccruz[0] = (vector1[1] * vector2[2]) - (vector1[2] * vector2[1]);
        veccruz[1] = -(vector1[0] * vector2[2]) - (vector1[2] * vector2[0]);
        veccruz[2] = (vector1[0] * vector2[1]) - (vector1[1] * vector2[0]); 
        return new veccruz[i];
    }
} //cierre productocruz
```

Comment: Los parámetros contienen errores sintacticos. Esto es debido a que i no debería formar parte de los parámetros de tu método.

Comment: @RuslanLópez gracias , hice la corrección pero ahora me aparecen estos errores (aparecen tres veces) class' expected en la invocacion del metodo ¿ que errores estoy comtiendo ? gracias nuevamente 
        productocruz(veccruz[],vector1[] ,vector2[]);

Comment: No hace falta que pongas los corchetes en la llamada a la función, sólo los nombres de las variables. Si es en la definición, ¿los corchetes deberían ir delante o detrás del nombre de la variable?

Comment: El tipo de dato es int[], pero seguramente igual necesitarás más correcciones.